# NSInternalInconsistencyException while deleting/inserting rows in UITableView

Tags: uitableview, ios5, cell

I need to create an app with tableView. For now I can just load/reload all data in my table. To add/delete operation tableView has editing mode. But the problem is that in this mode tableView shows standart add/delete buttons. But I don't need this buttons. In Apple tutorial I found other way to do add/delete row like this:

```
[data removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[data addObject:[[chooseTypeCell alloc]init]];
NSIndexPath *insertIndexPaths=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[data count] inSection:0]; 
NSIndexPath *deleteIndexPaths=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[[self view] beginUpdates];
[[self view] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:insertIndexPaths] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[[self view] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:deleteIndexPaths] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[[self view] endUpdates];
```

But it causes an error =(.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid table view update.  The application has requested an update to the table view that is inconsistent with the state provided by the data source.'

In my case I'm using object, which is subclass of UITableViewController, with UITableViewdataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols. In this object the view variable is connected with my UITableView. As a result, UITableView connects with the only it's controller. In this controller I defined these methods:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

#######>>>>> right code =)

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section


#######>>>>> in comment section

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath
toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

#######>>>>> without any code or cap

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath
toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

#######>>>>> right code =)

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
#######>>>>> in comment section

 - (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

 - (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

#######>>>>> without any code or cap

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
*)indexPath

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
*)indexPath

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
*)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Error like this:

> Assertion failure in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _computeRowUpdates], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-1912.3/UITableViewSupport.m:386
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid table view
>   update.  The application has requested an update to the table view
>   that is inconsistent with the state provided by the data source.'

May appear because your UITable-Data class is wrong defined.
You need to pay your attention to this methods:

> -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
>   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
>   -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Also you need to check your animation code. All indexes must be taken from **result data structure**.

In Apple Documentation:

> Deletion and reloading operations within an animation block specify
>   which rows and sections in the original table should be removed or
>   reloaded; insertions specify which rows and sections should be added
>   to the resulting table. The index paths used to identify sections and
>   rows follow this model. Inserting or removing an item in a mutable
>   array, on the other hand, may affect the array index used for the
>   successive insertion or removal operation; for example, if you insert
>   an item at a certain index, the indexes of all subsequent items in the
>   array are incremented.

In my case: error arises in  **insertRowsAtIndexPaths** function. Because all my changes (in my data) were applied by the time of execution. And new position of my UITableViewCell was ([data count]-1) meanwhile I used just [data count].

Thanks for your attention =).