# reloadRowsAtIndexPaths doesn't seem to work

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm using the Apple Developer Tutorial and trying to reload the rows that I click on.  The rows are not reloading.  I tried to wrap the reloadRows command between [beginUpdate]; and [endUpdate]; statements, but it still isn't reloading rows.  Any info/help? (I'm new to objective c, obviously).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListPrototypeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ToDoItem *toDoItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemName;
    if (toDoItem.completed)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    ToDoItem *tappedItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    tappedItem.itemName = @"YouTappedThis";
    tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Comment: I don't know that it makes a difference for the problem you're experiencing, but you probably should focus more on iOS7/iOS8 then iOS5...

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549620/why-does-reloadrowsatindexpaths-not-work-for-ios-5-0?rq=1

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted. Put a log in didSelectRowAtIndexPath to make sure that it's being called.